# How to set a variable inside of @RequestMapping, in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am very new to Spring Boot and have the following code

```
public String setRedirectURL(){
    return "/redirect/" + this.statusQueryToken;
}

@RequestMapping( /* This should be the return-value of setRedirectURL */)
public URL getRedirectURL(){

}
```

Basically, I want the value inside of @RequestMapping to be a variable, which is the return value of setRedirectURL.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You should explain what your actual *problem* is as it's likely whatever you're trying to do could be achieved in some other - legal - way (gut feeling tells me `@PathVariable`). Relevant reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thank you! I will read up on it.